# Close sessions in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python-3.x, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I got the following issue in Flask app when reaching the max limit of connections in Postgresql database:

```
WARNING Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

In each iteration of for loop, a query is sent to database using flask sqlalchemy. After 5 minutes, the database became unresponsive when attempting querying database. Just after the database is restarted, the application can query again, but it does not last long after the issue appears again.

The query is invoked from a function as the following:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()

class Table(db.Model):
    @classmethod
    def get_records_counter(cls):
        records_counter = db.session.query(
            func.count(Table.id).label('counter'))\
            .filter(func.date_trunc('day', Table.date) == func.date_trunc('day', func.now()))\
            .all()
        return records_counter.pop()

class CounterService:
    @classmethod
    def get_counter(cls):
        counter = Table.get_records_counter().counter

        return counter
```

The execution of `db.session.query()` is supposed to ensure that sessions are created and removed with the request/response cycle, and should be fine in most cases.

Should I include `db.session.remove()` to finish the connection or additional steps should be considered? In that scenario, the code would look like as follows:

```
class Table(db.Model):
    def remove_session(self):
        db.session.remove()

    @classmethod
    def get_records_counter(cls):
        records_counter = db.session.query(
            func.count(Table.id).label('counter'))\
            .filter(func.date_trunc('day', Table.date) == func.date_trunc('day', func.now()))\
            .all()
        cls.remove_session()
        return records_counter.pop()
```

What should be the proper way to close, not just reset the session as it is done with `db.session.close()`?

Thanks for your advice

Comment: You're right that flak-sqlalchemy should be removing the sessions automatically.  Can you provide a [mre]?  There isn't enough here to reproduce the problem.

Comment: So how did you handle it, after all?

Comment: @BogdanPrădatu I had an asynchronous function which used to create lots of connections to database. I went to the path to inspect why too many connections were created. Then, I realized an issue in the function called remotely and removed stale SQL invocations. I did not apply any fix related to SQL Alchemy, but just SQL queries.